# How to assign a value of type T to data[i] of type uchar without any loss?

Tags: c++, opencv

## Scenario

I want to create  my own `SetChannel` function that will set a specific channel of an image. For example, I have an image `input` of type `CV_16UC3` (BGR image of type `ushort`) and I want to change the green channel (=1 due to zero based index) to an `ushort` value of `32768`. For this, I invoke `SetChannel(input,1,32768)`.

```
template<typename T>
void SetChannel(Mat mat, uint channel, T value)
{
    const uint channels = mat.channels();
    if (channel + 1 > channels)
        return;

    T * data = (T*)mat.data;

// MBPR             : number of Memory Block Per Row
// Mat.step         : number of byte per row
// Mat.elemSize1()  : number of byte per channel
const unsigned int MBPR = mat.step / mat.elemSize1();

// N                : total number of memory blocks
const unsigned int N = mat.rows * MBPR;

for (uint i = channel; i < N; i += channels)
    data[i] = value;

}
```

I prefer working in a single loop than nested looping so I define the number of iteration `N` as given above.

The code above works as expected **but** some other people said the part

```
T * data = (T*)mat.data;
```

is a code smell and regarded as a badly designed program.

Now I want to rewrite the new one with another approach as follows.
It is not working as expected because I don't know how to assign `T value` to `data[i]` of type `uchar`.

```
template<typename T>
void SetChannel(Mat mat, uint channel, T value)
{
    const uint channels = mat.channels();
    if (channel + 1 > channels)
        return;

    uchar * data = mat.data;


    const unsigned int N = mat.rows * mat.step;// byte per image
    const unsigned int bpc = mat.elemSize1();// byte per channel
    const unsigned int bpp = mat.elemSize(); // byte per pixel
    for (uint i = channel * bpc; i < N; i += bpp)
        //data[i] = value;
}
```

## Question

How to assign `value` of type `T` to `data[i]` of type `uchar` without any loss?

For those who don't know how `Mat` is, the following might be useful.

## About OpenCV `Mat` class

OpenCV provides a bunch of types of images. For example,

- `CV_8UC1` represents gray scale image type in which each pixel has one channel of type `uchar`.
- `CV_8UC3` represents BGR (not RGB) image type in which each pixel has three channels, each of type `uchar`.
- `CV_16UC3` represents BGR (not RGB) image type in which each pixel has three channels, each of type `ushort`.
- etc.

`Mat` is the class to encapsulate image. It has several attributes and functions. Let me list some of them that I will use in this question so you can understand my scenario better.

- `Mat.data`: pointer of type `uchar` pointing to a block of image pixels.
- `Mat.rows`: number of rows
- `Mat.channels()`: number of channels per pixel
- `Mat.elemSize1()` (ended with 1): number of byte per channel
- `Mat.elemSize()`: number of byte per pixel. 
  `Mat.elemSize() = Mat.channels() * Mat.elemSize1()`.
- `Mat.step`: number of byte per row

Here `Mat.step` can be thought as the product of 
 - "effective" number of pixels per row (let me name it as EPPR), 
 - number of channels per pixel or `Mat.channels()`, and 
 - number of byte per channel or `Mat.elemSize1()`.

Mathematically,

```
 Mat.step = EPPR  * Mat.elemSize() 
 Mat.step = EPPR * Mat.channels() * Mat.elemSize1()
```

Let me define `EPPR * Mat.channels()` as memory blocks per row (`MBPR`). If you know the correct term for `MBPR`, let me know.

As a result,  `MBPR = Mat.step / Mat.elemSize1()`.

Comment: You should have a test in the template that checks T to ensure it's compatible with a uchar, and then use `static_cast<T*>` instead of C-casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from someone offline. Hopefully it is useful for others as well.

```
template<typename T>
void SetChannel(Mat mat, uint channel, T value)
{
    const uint channels = mat.channels();
    if (channel + 1 > channels)
        return;


    uchar * data = mat.data;
    const unsigned int N = mat.rows * mat.step;// byte per image
    const unsigned int bpc = mat.elemSize1();// byte per channel
    const unsigned int bpp = mat.elemSize(); // byte per pixel
    const unsigned int bpu = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uchar);// bits per uchar
    for (uint i = channel * bpc; i < N; i += bpp)
        for (uint j = 0; j < bpc; j++) 
            data[i + j] = value >> bpu * j;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to nested looping, this new method runs slower than the previous one by a factor of about 2.